# Showing something is a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I've been asked to show that -

> If $A = \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ then $z-1$ is a prime in $A$. (Here $z-1$ means the corresponding coset of $z-1$ in $A$.)

For this I quotiented by the ideal $(z-1)$ which gives $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$
How do I show that this is an integral domain?
(It'll imply $(z-1)$ is a prime ideal and hence $z-1$ is a prime.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've reduced your problem to showing that $x^2 + y^2$ is prime in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$.

To make things even simpler, remember that in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, being prime and being irreducible are the same thing (follows, for example, from $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ being a UFD).

Can you show that no non-constant polynomials divide $x^2 + y^2$?

Comment: Thanks. I got it. The other way I was thinking was isn't R[x,y]/(x²+y²) = R[x] + y.R[x] ? Which is an ID. Hence done?

Comment: Putting an '$=$' there is a little misleading, since you still have the relation $x^2 + y^2 = 0$.  Regardless you'll still have to prove it's an integral domain, the representation as $\mathbb{R}[x] + y\mathbb{R}[x]$ doesn't resolve anything.  Note that if you replaced $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{C}$ then you wouldn't have a domain anymore, because $x^2 + y^2 = (x + iy)(x-iy)$